# ¿Cómo recibir parámetro de un objeto para almacenarlo en una clase?

Tags: java, clase, método

estoy desarrollando unos ejercicios en Java, pero quedo trabado.

Primero: Necesito saber si voy bien, o hay algún error en mi código con lo que me piden.

Segundo: En el punto **d** no entiendo como recibir parámetro de un objeto para almacenarlo en la clase Caja, y que luego devuelva esa cantidad de ventas almacenadas. Y en el punto **e** tengo la gran duda de como desarrollarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Clase Venta:**

```
public class Venta {
private int valor;

public Venta(int ventas){
    valor=ventas;
}

public int getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(int valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}
```

**Clase Compra:**

```
public class Compra {
private int valor;

public Compra(int compras){
    valor=compras;
    }

public int getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(int valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}
```

**Clase Caja:**

```
public class Caja {
public float calculaSaldo(float ventas, float compras){
    float calculo = ventas - compras;
    return calculo;
}

public int mayorVenta(int venta1, int venta2){
    int mayorV = Math.max(venta1, venta2);
    return mayorV;
}

public int mayorCompra(int compra1, int compra2){
    int mayorC = Math.max(compra1, compra2);
    return mayorC;
}
```

Les agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Hola Mario. En los métodos, qué tipos de parametros conoces que puedan ser usados para pasar información?

Comment: Simplemente declara un método `addVenta(Venta v)`, puedes pasar objetos como parámetros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que lo primero que preguntabas es si vas bien, pues la verdad es que no ;) No es que el código esté mal, pero no vas bien encaminado. Empezemos:

Si te fijas en el diagrama que has adjuntado, la clase Caja tiene dos relaciones de agregación, una con la clase Compra y otra con la clase Venta. Estas dos relaciones te dice el diagrama que han de llamarse, respectivamente, **compras** y **ventas**. Por tanto, en tu clase Compra deberás definir atributos que te permitan gestionar esas dos agregaciones (¿alguien ha dicho listas? ;) )

Los puntos *d* y *e* son análogos. Lo que te dice el enunciado es que has de declarar un método cuyo parámetro sea del tipo Compra o Venta y, ese objeto has de añadirlo a la agregación de la que hablaba en el punto anterior. El resultado del método será el número de elementos que tengas en la agregación que corresponda. Ejemplo:

```
public int addVenta(Venta nuevaVenta) {
   ventas.add(nuevaVenta);
   return ventas.size();
}
```

Siguiendo esta línea, los métodos **calculaSaldo**, **mayorVenta** y **mayorCompra** tendrán que basarse en el contenido de estas listas, pero con que tengas un poco de vista verás que hay una forma muy fácil de optimizarlos... aunque lo dejaré aquí por ahora para que intentes pensar tú mismo la solución :)

Espero haberte servido de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración.